# ConstraintLayout cannot scale down chained ImageViews

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I've created a simple layout containing two ImageViews and one TextView. ImageViews need to be placed horizontally next to each other. I tried to use a spread chain to achieve that but ImageViews cannot be scale down to fit the screen.

[image]

**EDIT**

When i used a nested LinearLayout it works as i want it to work.

[image]

ImageViews are fully visible.

**Layout:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/logo_constraint_layout_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
tools:context=".LogoActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo_image_logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo_image_logo_content_description"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/logo_text_view_continue_message"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/logo_image_name"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo_image_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo_image_name_content_description"
    android:src="@drawable/name"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/logo_text_view_continue_message"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/logo_image_logo"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/logo_text_view_continue_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/logo_margin_bottom_continue_message"
    android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_regular"
    android:text="@string/logo_continue_message"
    android:textColor="@color/material_grey"
    android:textSize="@dimen/logo_text_size_continue_message"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logo_image_logo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If it works with nested LinearLayout could you please post an image of what you expect it to look like?

Comment: @plaskoff added what is suppose to look like

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong about your need, Try the layout below .

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".DemoActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="yellow"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.437"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

With `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"` both `Images Views` will share same weight.

Comment: It's not working. ImageViews are still getting cut off.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

on your `ImageViews`. `wrap_content` is forcing a size while `match_constraint` (`0dp`) will allow the images to grow/shrink as they need to.